# Button Text Initialization in flutter with SwitchListTile

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, button

I have a SwitchListTile in my App that determine the text that should be written on another button based on its value. Everything is working fine except for one thing which is that the first time you open the app, the initial text on the button will be nothing '' just as it was declared first time until I switch the SwitchListTile for the first time. So I want to know how to make the text appear from the moment you enter this page.

This is my code:

```
static String buttonText='';


SwitchListTile(
          title: const Text('Enable Bluetooth'),
          value: _bluetoothState.isEnabled,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            // Do the request and update with the true value then
            future() async {
              // async lambda seems to not working
              if (value) {
                await FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.requestEnable();
                setState(() {buttonText = "Press to start collection" ;   });


              } else {
                await FlutterBluetoothSerial.instance.requestDisable();
                setState(() {buttonText = "Please enable bluetooth in your device" ;   });
              }
            }

            future().then((_) {
              setState(() {});
            });
          },
        ),

.......................

ElevatedButton(


                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.red,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical:40),
            textStyle:
            const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),

                onPressed: () {
                if(_bluetoothState.isEnabled){
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const BluetoothConnectionTask()),

                  );
                }
                },
                child:  Text(
                  buttonText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28,color: Colors.black, letterSpacing: 2.0),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: I think you should declare the default value for the buttonText(If there is any), or in the initstate where you can assign as per your usecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the Text widget set in your elevated button as below.

```
    Text(
 _bluetoothState.isEnabled ? "Press to start collection" : "Please enable bluetooth in your device",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28,color: Colors.black, letterSpacing: 2.0),
                    )
```

And remove

```
setState(() {buttonText = "Press to start collection" ;   });

setState(() {buttonText = "Please enable bluetooth in your device" ;   });
```

from the onChanged method.

It is not working from first time because, onChanged method will get call when you interact with the SwitchListTile.

If still it's not working, Please let me know with the issue.

Comment: Another Big thanks to you. that did work perfectly